# how to identify why lookup failed in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl, visual-studio-2012

i have created an ETL package and having a lookup to match userid in db.
i checked in dataviewer what data is going as input to my lookup. the data is correct and the table i used in lookup to match also having data for that input but still i am getting error that no matching records found.

> **example for my schemario:** i have a view that fetches data like
>   orderby, orderno, orderdate. **orderby is a usercuid nchar(64)**. i have a
>   Dim in Dw named DimUser which is having usercuid. and i have to get
>   DimUserId for matching usercuid.  in my input data i am getting
>   **orderby as "User1"**  and in my DimUser there is record with
>   **usercuid=User1**

but **still ETL is failing with no matching records**... anybody could suggest how could i find out what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep in mind that a full cache lookup works in memory and not in SQL server. Thus, collation etc are not considered: spacing and capitalization makes a difference!

Answer (score 0):

i got a strange behaviour. the field was nchar(64). hence i needed to trim it(RTRIM) in input query as well as lookup query. and it worked!!!

Comment: SSIS lookups are actually .net string comparisons. Therefore, they must be EXACTLY the same to match. SQL 'where' clauses are much more permissive regarding whitespace and capitalization.